# Calculating first passage time/extinction time of a simple birth death continuous time markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am working on a biological stochastic modeling problem which involves the simple continuous time birth death markov process of one species: $$*\rightarrow X\rightarrow *$$
Where $X$ can either increase by 1 (a random event with constant propensity) or decrease by one (a random event with propensity directly proportional to the value of $X$).

Possible values of $X$ are all non-negative integers. I need a method to calculate the probability distribution of the first passage time where $X\rightarrow 0$, for initial conditions drawn from the steady state distribution of $X$ (which I know is a Poisson distribution). Alternatively, the initial condition could be fixed at a given value if this would make the calculations simpler. Alternatively, some arbitrary upper bound for $X$ could be chosen if this makes calculations simpler.

Comment: Note that, generally speaking, starting from a steady state distribution yields *simpler* formulas than starting from a fixed point. But, in the present case, does there really exist any stationary distribution (that is, not concentrated on $0$)? Note that state $0$ is absorbing hence, again in full generality, with full probability, either $X_t\to\infty$, or $X_t$ hits $0$ and then $X_t$ stays at $0$ indefinitely (and with the transitions you describe, $X_t$ hits $0$ almost surely).

Comment: The state $0$ is not absorbing. The propensity of $X$ to increase by one is constant regardless of the value of $X$.